# Making an air captive runtime bundle (for dummies level)

Tags: flash, air

I'm trying to make a stand alone captive runtime bundle for Mac.
So far I've worked mainly on and for windows and this is pretty new to me.

I got Java and the Air SDK on my macbook. I installed Java and installed(?) the Air SDK. The SDK shows up under "**devices**".

Now I understand I have to use ADT in the SDK to create a captive runtime bundle. I just don't know where to start really.

On my windows machine I have my `.fla` and from flash on my windows machine I can create an Air intermediate `.airi` file.

Can someone point me in the direction of what to do next ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can export this from Adobe Animate CC on your MacBook if you have a copy.